# Getting Values from a class & store them in an ArrayList

Tags: java, android, methods, arraylist

I have some images & sounds set in separate classes.I want to call them in my main activity. I want to put all three images from

```
 a1.setRightImage(R.drawable.play_blue_1);      
                List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

l1.add(R.drawable.play_blue_2);

l1.add(R.drawable.play_blue_3);
```

in an Array List and use them to set on different ImageViews.

```
             //Setting sound at start
            q1.setQuestionSound(R.raw.touch_blue);
             //First Image
            a1.setRightImage(R.drawable.play_blue_1);
            // Second list contains two images      
            List<Integer> l1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            l1.add(R.drawable.play_blue_2);
            l1.add(R.drawable.play_blue_3);
            //Adding them to the answer object                    
            a1.setWrongImages(l1);

            //Another Image 
            a1.setBigImage(R.drawable.big_play_blue);
            a1.setSuccessSound(R.raw.thats_correct);
            a1.setFailureSound(R.raw.no_its_wrong);

            q1.setAnswer(a1);
```

I am using this in my Main Activity am not able to get output . Its printing null.
I just want to get the data and print the obtained result values:

```
myArrayList.add(gpQuestion.getAnswer().getRightImage());
    myArrayList.addAll(gpQuestion.getAnswer().getWrongImages());
    arrayList.add(myArrayList.get(0));
    arrayList.add(myArrayList.get(1));

    for (int i = 0; i < arrayList.size(); i++) {
        arrayList.add(myArrayList.get(i));
        System.out.println(myArrayList.get(i));
    }
```

Atleast if I print them, I can use them in my methods.Thank you.

Comment: What do you mean by "separate classes"? Are those classes POJOs, if not what do they extend?

Comment: Yeah, Sorry, Just objects with setters & getters. I want to call them in my main Activity. Upto this I just Googled & got the matter. Now , I am stuck with the first mentioned bit of code in my above question. As I have one success Image & a list containing two images. I want to know how to call them & use in my app's Main Actiivity.

Answer (score 0):

better to use SharedPreferences

http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html

OR

Application Class

http://www.devahead.com/blog/2011/06/extending-the-android-application-class-and-dealing-with-singleton/

Comment: That's ok , but I don't need to store the data for a long while, Also I need to reuse the code in long-run on many Activities. That's why I am stuck with objects only.